# How to get json fields?

Tags: json, swift

I follow a lesson from one course
And I need to get json, but i want get another json than in a lesson.

So this is my json:
https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?q=half

And code:

```
struct Card {
    var cardId: String
var name: String
var imageUrl: String
var text: String

init?(dict: [String: AnyObject]){
    guard let name = dict["name"] as? String,
        let cardId = dict["cardId"] as? String,
        let imageUrl = dict["imageUrl"] as? String,
        let text = dict["text"] as? String else { return nil }

self.cardId = cardId
self.name = name
self.imageUrl = imageUrl
self.text = text
}
}

class CardNetworkService{
     private init() {}

static func getCards(url: String, completion: @escaping(GetCardResponse) -> ()) {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }

    NetworkService.shared.getData(url: url) { (json) in
        do {
            print ("ok1")
            let response = try GetCardResponse(json: json)
            print ("ok2")
            completion(response)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
}

class NetworkService {

private init() {}

static let shared = NetworkService()

func getData(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Any) -> ()) {
    let session = URLSession.shared

    session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) 
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(json)
            }
            print(json)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        }.resume()
}
}


  struct GetCardResponse{
    let cards: [Card]

init(json: Any) throws {
    guard let array = json as? [[String: AnyObject]] else { throw NetworkError.failInternetError }

    var cards = [Card]()
    for dictionary in array {
        guard let card = Card(dict: dictionary) else { continue }
        cards.append(card)
    }
    self.cards = cards
}
   }
```

Problem in **struct GetCardResponse** and **[[String: AnyObject]]** because I dont know how to parse this type of json. I tried to change them in the likeness of json. But I dont really understand how it works and in which part of code i need to put json["data"] or something like this... Help pls. I just want get json fields **tcgplayer_id, name, art_crop**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong get entry of `data` field.
First you need get `data` field in json. And parse to deeper.

Try use the code.

```
struct GetCardResponse{
  let cards: [Card]

  init(json: Any) throws {
    guard let jsonObject = json as? [String: Any], let data = jsonObject["data"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] else { throw NetworkError.failInternetError }

    var cards = [Card]()
    for dictionary in data {
      guard let card = Card(dict: dictionary) else { continue }
      cards.append(card)
    }
    self.cards = cards
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
`init` function in Card has something wrong. In your json `cardId` is not found

`Card` class maybe like this because `cardId`, `imageUrl`, `text` maybe not found. It is optional

```
struct Card {
  var cardId: String?
  var name: String
  var imageUrl: String?
  var text: String?

  init?(dict: [String: AnyObject]){
    guard let name = dict["name"] as? String else { return nil }

    self.cardId = dict["cardId"] as? String
    self.name = name
    self.imageUrl = dict["imageUrl"] as? String
    self.text = dict["text"] as? String
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It almost works! But now program stop at line:  guard let card = Card(dict: dictionary) else { continue } 
Error: **Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]'** and fix don't help

Comment: @Marina I updated my answer a few minute. Please try again.

Comment: @ThanVu Thank you, but I commented out the line with **cardId** but programm still end at line  guard let card = Card(dict: dictionary) else { continue }

Comment: @Marina YES, Because your code is require `cardId` field. I did update

Answer (score 1):

As of your code, you can parse the required details as:

```
struct Card {
var cardId: String = ""
var name: String = ""
var imageUrl: String = ""
var text: String = ""

init(dict: [String: Any]) {

    if let obj = dict["name"] {
        self.name = "\(obj)"
    }

    if let obj = dict["tcgplayer_id"] {
        self.cardId = "\(obj)"
    }

    if let obj = dict["image_uris"] as? [String:Any], let url = obj["art_crop"] {
        self.imageUrl = "\(url)"
    }

    if let obj = dict["oracle_text"] {
        self.text = "\(obj)"
    }
  }

  static func models(array: [[String:Any]]) -> [Card] {
    return array.map { Card(dict: $0) }
  }
}

class CardNetworkService{
  private init() {}

  static func getCards(url: String, completion: @escaping([Card]?) -> ()) {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }

    NetworkService.shared.getData(url: url) { (json) in
            print ("ok1")
            if let jData = json as? [String:Any], let data = jData["data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                let response = Card.models(array: data)
                completion(response)
            }
            completion(nil)
    }
  }
}

class NetworkService {

  private init() {}

  static let shared = NetworkService()

  func getData(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Any) -> ()) {
    let session = URLSession.shared

    session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(json)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        }.resume()
  }
}

CardNetworkService.getCards(url: "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?q=half") { (res) in
print(res ?? [])
 }
```

Just paste this code in playground and it'll work.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using **`Codable`** to parse the JSON data like so,

Create the models like,

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let cards: [Card]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case cards = "data"
    }
}
struct Card: Decodable {
    let tcgplayerId: Int
    let name: String
    let artCrop: String
}
```

Now parse your JSON data using,

```
if let data = data {
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
        print(response)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

You can access the properties in `cards` of `response` like so,

```
response.cards.first?.tcgplayerId
```